# Android studio Failed to find: com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run my gradle file with an already existing android project. The only error that I have with this application is `Failed to find: com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0`. Below is my gradle file. Is there something that I need to change to get it to work?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you require additional information. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a search on Maven Central at http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfloatingactionbutton that library exists, so I think the problem may be that you haven't added a `repositories` statement to your build script to let it resolve dependencies; the one you've got in the `buildscript` block is only to resolve build system plugins, not build dependencies. I know it's confusing. Add this block at the top level:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I'm assuming also that you have a project with a flat directory structure and a single **build.gradle** file; when Android Studio creates projects via the wizard it uses a nested directory structure with multiple **build.gradle** files, and it normally adds boilerplate at the top-level build file so that you don't have to add this `repositories` block to each individual module's build file. If that's the case and that's in place, then this remedy won't work, so you'll have to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "Global Gradle Settings" in Android Studio is NOT set for "Offline Work"