# Add dependencies on an Android Studio nested directory structure project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm struggling to add an external dependency in my project, adding the

```
compile 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v0.9.3'
```

in my build.gradle file.

I've also added

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

on the top level build.gradle file.

I have an Android Studio project with nested structure (and so nested build.gradle files) and this is my error log:

> 23:24:23.997 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   23:24:23.997 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   23:24:23.998 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v0.9.3.
>   23:24:23.998 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]      Searched in the following locations:
>   23:24:24.000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/v0.9.3/android-DecoView-charting-v0.9.3.pom
>   23:24:24.004 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/v0.9.3/android-DecoView-charting-v0.9.3.jar
>   23:24:24.004 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          file:/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/v0.9.3/android-DecoView-charting-v0.9.3.pom
>   23:24:24.004 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          file:/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/v0.9.3/android-DecoView-charting-v0.9.3.jar
>   23:24:24.004 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          file:/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/v0.9.3/android-DecoView-charting-v0.9.3.pom
>   23:24:24.005 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          file:/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting/v0.9.3/android-DecoView-charting-v0.9.3.jar
>   23:24:24.005 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
>   23:24:24.005 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]          trunk:app:unspecified
>   23:24:24.005 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   23:24:24.005 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
>   23:24:24.007 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   23:24:24.008 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)

I've stumbled up on the first answer of this question: 
[Android studio Failed to find: com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551270/android-studio-failed-to-find-com-getbasefloatingactionbutton1-3-0)

where it says that, on a such structure project, it's not possible to add a dependency in this way.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

**EDIT** 
I tried the solution proposed by @Sharj. It works fine to resolve the dependency of DecoView-Charting.
Anyway I tried to add this new dependency

```
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
```

and the compilation fails with this error:

> 19:07:43.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   19:07:43.256 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   19:07:43.259 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   19:07:43.261 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>   19:07:43.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   19:07:43.275 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
>   19:07:43.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   19:07:43.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
>   19:07:43.283 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   19:07:43.284 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>   19:07:43.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   19:07:43.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>   19:07:43.289 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>   19:07:43.290 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   19:07:43.290 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>   19:07:43.291 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   19:07:43.291 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>   19:07:43.291 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   19:07:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
>   19:07:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>   19:07:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>   19:07:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>   19:07:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>   19:07:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>   19:07:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>   19:07:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>   19:07:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>   19:07:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>   19:07:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>   19:07:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>   19:07:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>   19:07:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>   19:07:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>   19:07:43.298 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>   19:07:43.298 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
>   19:07:43.298 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
>   19:07:43.299 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   19:07:43.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>   19:07:43.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>   19:07:43.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
>   19:07:43.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   19:07:43.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>   19:07:43.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>   19:07:43.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>   19:07:43.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>   19:07:43.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>   19:07:43.302 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>   19:07:43.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>   19:07:43.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.305 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>   19:07:43.305 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.306 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>   19:07:43.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   19:07:43.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
>   19:07:43.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   19:07:43.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>   19:07:43.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   19:07:43.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>   19:07:43.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>   19:07:43.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>   19:07:43.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>   19:07:43.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
>   19:07:43.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
>   19:07:43.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
>   19:07:43.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
>   19:07:43.314 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
>   19:07:43.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
>   19:07:43.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
>   19:07:43.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>   19:07:43.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>   19:07:43.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 57 more
>   19:07:43.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
>   19:07:43.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
>   19:07:43.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:854)
>   19:07:43.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$processResources$2.call(Unknown Source)
>   19:07:43.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:159)
>   19:07:43.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:79)
>   19:07:43.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
>   19:07:43.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 63 more
>   19:07:43.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/a-m/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
>   19:07:43.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
>   19:07:43.319 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
>   19:07:43.319 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 68 more
>   19:07:43.319 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]

Comment: You add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to repositories?

Comment: What's your error? Also paste your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

and in the same `build.gralde` file

```
dependencies {

   //Other dependencies up here 

   compile 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v0.9.3'
}
```

Comment: It's a bit strange. Your answer works properly with that dependency. If I try to add this one `compile 'com.github.futuresimple:android-floating-action-button:1.10.1'` it fails:
`Exception is:Exception is:
19:23:47.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
19:23:47.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execu....`

Comment: @cq5beginner post the complete exception in your question. There must be some hint why there's a problem in error.